# .Net RIA Services - Membership API - SQL Server?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, asp.net-membership, wcf-ria-services

I have an existing ASP.Net application using the Membership API. The Membership API is hosted in SQL Server (not SQL Express) and is in the same database as the application data. I want to port the application to a Silverlight Business Application. I need to be able to tell RIA Services where the current membership data is and I have not been able to find an example that works.

This should really be a no brainer if MS wants businesses to adapt this technology - I have spent the better part of 1/2 day and I am totally frustrated and very aggravated. I would think that many developers would find themselves in the same scenario. Has anyone been successful with this?

I have set up the providers in the Web application project of the solution. I ran the confoguration tool and was able to see my existing users so I know the web.config stuff is working correctly.